# Xcode 6.1 GM Seed's autocomplete always terminate

Tags: xcode, swift, sourcekit

Today, I have downloaded Xcode 6.1 GM Seed from apple developer site so when I try to write in Swift it always crash.
Xcode's popup a notify:
SourceKit crash blah blah... Editor functionally temporary limited sometime like this.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Yeah, it has bugs. Try downgrading to 6.0.1. See http://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/2igf1y/xcode_61_gm_with_serious_bugs/

Comment: 6.1 GM v2 also constantly giving SourceKitCrashed message/alert

Comment: I need to use 6.1 and v2 is crashing constantly.

Comment: Try to delete ~Library/Developer/Xcode before installation.

Comment: @David Brilliant! Deleting ~/Library/Developer/Xcode did the trick.

Comment: Be careful to backup any archive you might care about before deleting ~/Library/Developer/Xcode

Comment: @chourobin Oh, you think that did the trick. But trust me... they'll be back. They *always* come back...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Exit Xcode. Delete ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and start it again.

Comment: For me this doesn't work. Very annoying when this message occurs every time you just start typing anything.

Comment: It works for a while and then it comes back again very fast. The Xcode make me nuts. I can hardly work with it.

Answer (score 5):

Delete `~/Library/Developer/Xcode` before installation.

Comment: Thanks David, but it's a root cause.